# SpringBatch write to different entities

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I have processed a "wrapperObject" (AimResponse in this case).

Depending on the property "type" I map to Document or SourceSpace object.

Then I need to persist these entities. I found an example similar to this one:

```
@Override
public void write(List<? extends List<AimResponse>> list)
    throws Exception {
    List<SourceSpace> sourceSpaces = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Document> documents = new ArrayList<>();
    for(List<AimResponse> item:list) {
        for(AimResponse i:item) {
            if(i.getType().indexOf("folder") >= 0) {
                SourceSpace sourceSpace = Mapper.aimResponseToSourceSpace(i);
                sourceSpace.setStatus(Status.FOUND.name());
                sourceSpaces.add(sourceSpace);
            } else if(i.getType().indexOf("document") >= 0) {
                Document document = Mapper.aimResponseToDocument(i);
                document.setStatus(Status.FOUND.name());
                documents.add(document);
            }
        }
    }
    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(sourceSpaces)) {
        sourceSpaceWriter.write(sourceSpaces);
    }
    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(documents)) {
        documentWriter.write(documents);
    }
    }
```

In this example I'm not able to instantiate JdbcBatchItemWriter but anyway I think should be better if the processor could split into 2 different lists and call 2 different writers each one with its own type but I guess it's not possible.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

[ClassifierCompositeItemWriter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriter.html) is what you are looking for. It allows you to classify items according to a given criteria and call the corresponding writer.

In your case, you can classify items based on their type (`i.getType()`) and use a writer for each type. You can find an example of how to use that writer [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/master/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/test/java/org/springframework/batch/item/support/ClassifierCompositeItemWriterTests.java).